# There are some design pattern errors in my javascript source

Tags: javascript

I tried to run this code, but console shows me this error message.

Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Stack().push')

I know the alternative way is using prototype to complete this code, but I am trying to study this kind of pattern.
Please let me know solve this error.

```
var Stack = function() {
this.repository = [1];

debug('current this.repository: ' + this.repository);


function push(data) {
    debug('this: ' + this);
    debug('current this.repository: ' + this.repository);
    debug('after pushing data: ' + this.repository);
}

function pop() {
    if (!this.repository.length) {
        return null;
    }

    var result = this.repository[this.repository.length - 1];
    this.repository = this.repository.slice(0, this.repository.length - 1);
    debug('after poping data: ' + this.repository);

    return result;
}

};

Stack().push(9);
Stack().push(10);
Stack().pop();
```

Comment: what is this pattern called?

Comment: Why you're reinventing [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) ?

Comment: did you notice that you didn't implement push? you just added debug messages..

Comment: your function `Stack` returns `undefined` ... `undefined` has no method called `push`

Comment: @NinaScholz - it's called Star Trek GNDN pattern ... goes nowhere, does nothing

Comment: Did you notice that you didn't export the functions or define them on the prototype? You need to do at least one.

Comment: Did you notice that you're using `this` when you're invoking your constructor without the `new` keyword ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor call with `new`. And some assignments for the public methods.

```js
var Stack = function () {
    this.repository = [1];
    document.write('current this.repository: ' + this.repository + '<br>');

    function push(data) {
        document.write('this: ' + this + '<br>');
        document.write('current this.repository: ' + this.repository + '<br>');
        this.repository.push(data); // was missing
        document.write('after pushing data: ' + this.repository + '<br>');
    }

    function pop() {
        if (!this.repository.length) {
            return null;
        }
        var result = this.repository[this.repository.length - 1];
        this.repository.slice(0, this.repository.length - 1); // works without assignment
        document.write('after poping data: ' + this.repository + '<br>');
        return result;
    }
    this.pop = pop;
    this.push = push;
};
var stack = new Stack();

document.write('stack.push(9) ' + stack.push(9) + '<br>');
document.write('stack.push(10) ' + stack.push(10) + '<br>');
document.write('stack.pop() ' + stack.pop() + '<br>');
```

For use without `new`, you can use the following pattern:

```js
var Stack = {
    repository: [1],

    push: function (data) {
        document.write('this: ' + this + '<br>');
        document.write('current this.repository: ' + this.repository + '<br>');
        this.repository.push(data); // was missing
        document.write('after pushing data: ' + this.repository + '<br>');
    },

    pop: function () {
        if (!this.repository.length) {
            return null;
        }
        var result = this.repository[this.repository.length - 1];
        this.repository.slice(0, this.repository.length - 1);
        document.write('after poping data: ' + this.repository + '<br>');
        return result;
    }
};

document.write('Stack.push(9) ' + Stack.push(9) + '<br>');
document.write('Stack.push(10) ' + Stack.push(10) + '<br>');
document.write('Stack.pop() ' + Stack.pop() + '<br>');
```

Comment: @JaromandaX use `new` doesn't mean functions have to be attached to a prototype.

Comment: When new Stack() is called, JavaScript does four things:

    1. It creates a new object.
    2. It sets the constructor property of the object to Stack.
    3. It sets up the object to delegate to Stack.prototype.
    4. It calls Stack() in the context of the new object.

Comment: @JaromandaX but doesn't mean `push` and `pop` have to be defined on the `Stack.prototype` ...

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just newbie of javascript developer. This answer would be the great guide line for me! thank you again.

Comment: Your aware your second example is a singleton, right ?

Comment: @naomik, i know that.